# Submodule for independent plugins

Tags: git, git-submodules

I’m looking for a way to organize my project’s repository. The project is closed source but it contains a single subfolder which I want to make publically available. That folder contains “plugins” that are called from the main project. All those plugins require that the main project is there, but of course the main project does not need them to work.

The usual approach would be to use a submodule for the plugins, but I’m not too happy with what this means to the main project. As the main development is completely separate from the plugins, I don’t want to mess up its history with updates from the plugins submodule, and I actually don’t want the plugins to be part of the main (core) program.

So what I rather want to have is the reverse situation where the main program is a submodule of the plugins repository so that the main development is completely independent from the plugins. The problem is that my program structure requires the plugins to be inside of the main directory tree, so that they can be accessed correctly.

Is there some standard approach to such a situation where the submodule is the “bigger” or “outer” repository? Or do you have another idea to solve this?

Comment: I think the history clutter is a non-issue; you could develop plugins separately, then right before a release, update all the submodules and commit once. It sounds like your real wish is not to have the main project have to be aware of the plugins at all, right?

Comment: There isn’t really going to be a release, so that’s not the problem. It’s more that the main project is some kind of a runtime for the plugins, so it is technically not aware of them, but of course made to work with them. But the set of available plugins is actually what is changing all the time while the main project will just receive maintenance updates.

Comment: Have you looked at the `sub-tree merge` strategy, which may give you some leverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

1. Simply do a separate clone of the plugins repo manually. Add "plugins" directory to the runtime repo's .gitignore file and put a note in the README detailing the location of the plugins repo and how to clone it. Plugins repo can be updated at any time with a simple `cd plugins; git pull`. You could add a post-receive hook on the main git repo locally to update the plugins repo if you wish to avoid extra steps, but this would only affect your local repo.
2. Use a submodule. In order to get the latest plugins into your runtime environment you'd have to do commits to track the head of the plugins submodule. E.g. `git add plugins; git commit -m "tracking latest plugins"`. Updating/deploying could then be done with `git pull; git submodule update --init --recursive`
3. Use a subtree. I don't think this is what you want, but you can read about it at [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html). Updating the plugins would require multiple steps which may not even be doable while in production.

If you have some sort of automated build system I'd consider a submodule. Otherwise I'd just go with 1 since it will have the least maintenance.